# Operator is part of the calculation string for calculator

Tags: c#

I am making a calculator in c#. the equation by the user is displayed in a textbox called textBoxInput and the result is displayed in labelResult. When I hit the 'equals' button a System.FormatException Exception occurs at `secondInt = int.Parse(textBoxInput.Text);` which to me means that the program is trying to convert the operator into an int aswell as the integers input by the user in textBoxInput. My question is how can I make the program just convert the first and secondInts's without trying to convert the operator aswell? I want to keep the entire equation in textBoxInput while the result is displayed in labelResult. Here is the enitre code for the calculator class which the problem exists in.

```
public partial class Calculator : Form
    {

        int firstInt;
        int secondInt;
        int result;
        string Operator;
        Boolean Op;

        public Calculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxInput.Text += ("1");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxInput.Text += ("2");
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxInput.Text += ("3");
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxInput.Text += ("4");
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxInput.Text += ("5");
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxInput.Text += ("6");
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxInput.Text += ("7");
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxInput.Text += ("8");
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxInput.Text += ("9");
        }

        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxInput.Text += ("0");
        }

        private void labelResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void buttonEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calculations application = new Calculations();
            secondInt = int.Parse(textBoxInput.Text);  

            switch (Operator)
            {
                case "/":
                    result = application.Division(firstInt, secondInt);
                    labelResult.Text = (firstInt + " / " + secondInt + "\n" + "= " + result);
                    break;

                case "+":
                    result = application.Addition(firstInt, secondInt);
                    labelResult.Text = (firstInt + " + " + secondInt + "\n" + "= " + result);
                    break;

                case "-":
                    result = application.Subtract(firstInt, secondInt);
                    labelResult.Text = (firstInt + " - " + secondInt + "\n" + "= " + result);
                    break;

                case "*":
                    result = application.Multiply(firstInt, secondInt);
                    labelResult.Text = (firstInt + " * " + secondInt + "\n" + "= " + result);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            firstInt = int.Parse(textBoxInput.Text);
            textBoxInput.Text += (" + ");
            Op = true;
            Operator = "+";

        }

        private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxInput.Text = "";
            labelResult.Text = "";
        }

        private void buttonMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            firstInt = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxInput.Text);

            Operator = "*";
            textBoxInput.Text += (" * ");
        }

        private void buttonSubtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            firstInt = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxInput.Text);

            Operator = "-";
            textBoxInput.Text += (" - ");
        }

        private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            firstInt = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxInput.Text);
            Operator = "/";
            textBoxInput.Text += (" / ");
        }

        private void button10_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxInput.Text += (".");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to write a parser which can read the `textBoxInput.Text` and split it up into the various components and calculate. There's no super easy way to do this if you allow several operators etc.

Comment: I answered a similar question a while back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080667/c-sharp-multiline-calculation/19080992#19080992

Comment: **Suggestion**: Just make one even handler, which all the numeric buttons subscribe to, and then do `Button btn=(Button)sender; textBoxInput.Text+=btn.Text;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
secondInt = int.Parse(textBoxInput.Text);
```

to this:

```
secondInt = int.Parse(textBoxInput.Text.Split('/', '+', '-', '*')[1].Trim());
```

And see if it helps.

I tried to simply answer the question, **not** delve into details of making a solid calculator application since the topic is too broad.

Comment: @ultrapulse Sure mate. By the time you click `buttonEquals`, the value inside the textbox is something like "5 + 3" and naturally enough `int.Parse` cannot convert this string value to an integer. We must first get rid of the operator sign. This is where `Split` function comes in. We just split this string value with either of the operator signs and take the second part (index value of 1) after this split. Then we trim it to get rid of any redundant space characters. Afterwards we send this value to the int.Parse method. I hope I made myself clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't use `int.Parse` by itself here. You are going to need to do a character-by-character inspection of the code and decide for yourself whether each piece is part of a value vs an operator - essentially building an AST. Then compute the AST using whichever precedence rules your calculator implements.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Mathematical Expressions Evaluator for .NET e.g: [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)

```
Expression e = new Expression("2 + 3 * 5");
Debug.Assert(17 == e.Evaluate());
```

For your case

```
Expression e = new Expression(textBoxInput.Text);
labelResult.Text = e.Evaluate().ToString();
```